# Multiple inheritance workaround in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns

```
interface IA {
    public void a();
}

class AB implements IA {
    @Override
    public void a() { System.out.println("a"); } // <---.

    public void b() { System.out.println("b"); }
}

class C {
    public void c() { System.out.println("c"); }
}


// My class:
class AC extends C implements IA {
    @Override
    public void a() { System.out.println("a"); } // duplicate code 
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AC ac = new AC();
        ac.a(); // "a"
        ac.c(); // "c"
    }
}
```

Using duplicate code does not seem to be a good idea, how could I design my class properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use composition and delegate, among other options:

```
interface IA {
    public void a ();
} 

interface IB {
    public void b ();
}

class A implements IA {
    @Override public void a () { /* code */ }
}

class B implements IB {
    @Override public void b () { /* code */ }
}

class AB implements IA, IB {
    final A a = new A();
    final B b = new B();
    @Override public void a () { a.a(); }
    @Override public void b () { b.b(); }
}
```

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks; I've been in C++ land all day.

Answer (score 3):

Java 8 introduces the concept of "default methods" - but before that you have no way around it.

Comment: Thats true but I still dont think we can call that multiple inheritance. There are still many restrictions for interfaces vs classes, like defining constructors , accessing variables other than local variables etc. Its sort of a compromise between mutiple inheritance and no multiple inheritance.  But yes it definitely adds the problem of refrencing same method defined in both the interfaces.

Comment: @Mustafasabir agreed (and for the record, I never considered it as multiple inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

You could make `a` a default method:

```
interface IA {
    public default void a(){ System.out.println("a"); }
}
```

Comment: This is a quick way but I *really* personally dislike that default methods were added to Java; the potential for making a mess when used improperly is very high. If you do this be sure to make sure you maintain a clear grasp on your code structure while developing.